# ng-class if else not working with repeat value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-class

I been trying to change a class if a tab in a repeat, depending in the title of the tab. snippet shown below

```
 <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" ng-class="{{tab.title}} === 'Logs' ? 'pull-right' : ''" active="tab.active">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div ng-include="tab.content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </tab>
```

But it's not working. I tried changing the tab.title to $index.

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" ng-class="{{$index}} === 1 ? 'pull-right' : ''">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div ng-include="tab.content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </tab>
```

try with and without surrounding it with {} and {{}}. but still. nothing works.

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

as always, thanks for your time.

----EDIT---------

well i found a post where there was a workaround. don't know what happen. but it works.
snippet shown below

```
              <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" class="{{ tab.title == 'Logs' ? 'pull-right':'' }} ">
            <div class=" col-md-12">
            <div ng-include="tab.content">
            </div>
```

Comment: as i describe. i have tried it with and without. but nothing changes.

Comment: What's `tab`? Is it your own directive?

Comment: Arh sry. forgot i was using it. no. it's [angular-ui bootstrap lib](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs).

Comment: You should've started with it, actually. It looks like there's no way to apply your own `ng-class` to `tab` directive (among others from that package). Check [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4172) for details - and possible workaround, involving using a custom function.

Comment: It works, because `class` (native attribute) is supplied with an Angular expression. ) You can post this as an answer, but I'd suggest changing your question a bit - it's actually `angular.ui/bootstrap` specific.

Comment: Actually, your question is 100% covered by [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1741).

Comment: @raina77ow i think that since you can explain what's wrong, you should do the answer post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in [the docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/docs/api/ng/directive/ngClass), value of `ng-class` is an expression that can be evaluated to a string, an object, or an array. That means you don't have to use `{{}}` there: simple...

```
ng-class="tab.title === 'Logs' ? 'pull-right' : ''"
```

... should suffice. In fact, it's cleaner to write it as an object:

```
ng-class="{'pull-right':tab.title === 'Logs'}"
```

Sadly, that won't solve your case, as you're trying to apply `ng-class` to a custom directive (created with angular-ui Bootstrap package). That directive uses `ng-class` in [its own template](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/b18dc8f9bc363a5897fcbd32561c9375096d184a/template/tabs/tab.html):

```
<li ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}">
  <a href ng-click="select()" tab-heading-transclude>{{heading}}</a>
</li>
```

... and it's created with `replace` flag set to true. This effectively means value of `ng-class` supplied by you will be glued together with value supplied by template, resulting in something ugly like:

```
<li ng-class="tab.title === 'Logs' ? 'pull-right' : '' {active: active, disabled: disabled}">
```

That certainly won't work as planned. In fact, there's a related issue ([**#1741**](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1741)) registered at the project's hub - which is closed with the following commentary:

> Using `ng-class` on a directive that uses `replace: true` is a very bad
>   idea. There are numerous issues around `replace: true` and even talk of
>   deprecating/removing it. But, unfortunately, it's not going anywhere
>   soon and the caveat released by the core Angular team was that use it,
>   but do so at your peril. I.e., use it knowing that doing so
>   incorrectly can break your DOM.
>
> I suspect this issue will not be addressed.

One possible workaround is using native class with an Angular expression supplied as its value:

```
class="{{tab.title === 'Logs' ? 'pull-right' : ''}}"
```

This won't be merged with a `<tab>` template class, as there's no such thing there - and you're clear to go!

Answer (score 2):

You should use this syntax for the `ng-class`. First the class name you want to set, second the condition to check for. Once it matches the condition, the class name will be added.

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" ng-class="{ 'pull-right': tab.title == 'Logs' }" active="tab.active">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div ng-include="tab.content">
        </div>
    </div>
</tab>
```

Comment: when i use it as you said. i get a [error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=40&p3=%7B%20'pull-right'%3A%20tab.title%20%3D%3D%3D%20'Logs'%20%7D%20%7Bactive%3A%20active%2CNaNisabled%3A%disabled%7D&p4=%7Bactive%3A%20active%2C%disabled%3A%disabled%7D) -

 Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 40 of the expression [{ 'pull-right': tab.title === 'Logs' }

Comment: Can you try using `==` (2 equals) instead of ´===` (3 equals)?

Comment: Nope. same thing happens

Comment: That is strange ... do you have same error when doing `ng-class="{ 'pull-right': true }"` ?

Comment: @MikeVranckx You're correct in general case, but that's not the one - it's `tab` directive, having its own quirks. Basically, the value specified in `ng-class` is concatenated to `tab` own ng-class definition; that's why string syntax just doesn't work without any errors in console, and object syntax throws an error.